# How to split string at any number followed by a period instead of a fixed delimiter

Tags: python, string

input:

```
string="1.Adam-Lee-Dotnet-9191919191-AdamLee@gmail.com-London-UK-Oracle-Banking2.Peter-Smith-Salesforce-9222291910-PeterSmith21@gmail.com-Mumbai-INDIA-Oracle-Engineering3.Harrison-Lu-Java-9223391910-HarrisonLu@gmail.com-Mumbai-INDIA-Samsung-Engineering4.Andrew-Joseph-Javascript-9200091910-AndrewJoseph@gmail.com-Toronto-CANADA-Dell-Engineering5.Larry-Ken-SQL-8880091910-LarryKen@gmail.com-Newyork-USA-HP-Management"
```

expected output:

```
[
    "1.Adam-Lee-Dotnet-9191919191-AdamLee@gmail.com-London-UK-Oracle-Banking", 
    "2.Peter-Smith-Salesforce-9222291910-PeterSmith21@gmail.com-Mumbai-INDIA-Oracle-Engineering",
    ...
]
```

Attempt: I have tried using a `string.split(range(0,5)+".")`. What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could split using a regex with lookaround assertions that assert 1+ digits followed by a dot to the right using `(?=\d+\.)`  and assert not the start of the string to the left using `(?<!^)`

```
(?<!^)(?=\d+\.)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/AR1qzR/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/g0wnFT)

```
import re

pattern = r"(?<!^)(?=\d+\.)"
string="1.Adam-Lee-Dotnet-9191919191-AdamLee@gmail.com-London-UK-Oracle-Banking2.Peter-Smith-Salesforce-9222291910-PeterSmith21@gmail.com-Mumbai-INDIA-Oracle-Engineering3.Harrison-Lu-Java-9223391910-HarrisonLu@gmail.com-Mumbai-INDIA-Samsung-Engineering4.Andrew-Joseph-Javascript-9200091910-AndrewJoseph@gmail.com-Toronto-CANADA-Dell-Engineering5.Larry-Ken-SQL-8880091910-LarryKen@gmail.com-Newyork-USA-HP-Management"                    

res = re.split(pattern, string)
print(res)
```

Output

```
[
 '1.Adam-Lee-Dotnet-9191919191-AdamLee@gmail.com-London-UK-Oracle-Banking',
 '2.Peter-Smith-Salesforce-9222291910-PeterSmith21@gmail.com-Mumbai-INDIA-Oracle-Engineering',
 '3.Harrison-Lu-Java-9223391910-HarrisonLu@gmail.com-Mumbai-INDIA-Samsung-Engineering',
 '4.Andrew-Joseph-Javascript-9200091910-AndrewJoseph@gmail.com-Toronto-CANADA-Dell-Engineering',
 '5.Larry-Ken-SQL-8880091910-LarryKen@gmail.com-Newyork-USA-HP-Management'
]
```

---

Or instead of splitting, you could also use a pattern to match 1 or more digits followed by a dot, and then match until the first occurrence of the same pattern or the end of the string.

```
\d+\..*?(?=\d+\.|$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JGktYx/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/gqF6FF)

```
import re
 
pattern = r"\d+\..*?(?=\d+\.|$)"
string="1.Adam-Lee-Dotnet-9191919191-AdamLee@gmail.com-London-UK-Oracle-Banking2.Peter-Smith-Salesforce-9222291910-PeterSmith21@gmail.com-Mumbai-INDIA-Oracle-Engineering3.Harrison-Lu-Java-9223391910-HarrisonLu@gmail.com-Mumbai-INDIA-Samsung-Engineering4.Andrew-Joseph-Javascript-9200091910-AndrewJoseph@gmail.com-Toronto-CANADA-Dell-Engineering5.Larry-Ken-SQL-8880091910-LarryKen@gmail.com-Newyork-USA-HP-Management"                    
 
res = re.findall(pattern, string)
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't usually reach for regular expressions first, but this cries out for `re.split`.

```
parts = re.split(r'(\d\.)`, string)
```

This does need a bit of post-processing.  It creates:

```
['', '1.', 'Adam-Lee-Dotnet-9191919191-AdamLee@gmail.com-London-UK-Oracle-Banking', '2.', 'Peter-Smith-Salesforce-9222291910-PeterSmith21@gmail.com-Mumbai-INDIA-Oracle-Engineering', ...
```

So you'll need to combine ever other element.

Comment: `\d+` so that numbers beyond 9 are handled?

Comment: No, if you need multidigit numbers, use `\d+`.

Comment: That's what I meant :)